# How to install Go Firebase Admin SDK v3.10.0 on Go 1.10.7?

Tags: firebase, go, windows-xp

I know I know... We have 2022 and the current version of Go Firebase Admin SDK is `V4.8.0` and GO is `1.18.1` so versions for SDK `v3.10.0` and `1.10.7` for GO are very outdated but I can't use the newest though I'd love to :/

I need to create a small script that will fetch some data from the local database, and send it periodically to Firestore. That database is running on **Windows XP 32bit** *(I agree that this is crazy, but there are running 2 "custom" programs - XP only - without any updates to newer versions :/ )*

I tried to run there a Go Firebase Admin SDK `v4.7.1` on Go `1.12.17` and the program runs but with an error `panic: Failed to find GetFileInformationByHandleEx procedure in kernel32.dll...` so I decided to try the last Go version with XP support [1.10](https://go.dev/doc/go1.10) with the last Go Firebase Admin SDK [v3.10.0](https://pkg.go.dev/firebase.google.com/go@v3.10.0+incompatible) ([Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/go#version_3100_-_30_october_2019)) which supports Go 1.10.

And I am able to build some simple base Go program, but I have no idea how to install a Go Firebase Admin SDK v3 version :/ I try `go get firebase.google.com/go` it try to install version v4 which is incompatible, but when I try `go get firebase.google.com/go@v3` (how it is described in [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/migrate-go-v4#developers_already_using_modules)) I receive `package firebase.google.com/go@v3: firebase.google.com/go@v3: invalid import path: malformed import path "firebase.google.com/go@v3": invalid char '@'` error.

Do you have any idea how can I install Go Firebase Admin SDK `v3.10.0` on Go `1.10.7`?
Or do u see any options to read/write data to Firestore from XP in a simpler way instead of creating a simple SDK with [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)?

Thanks!

Comment: "on Go 1.10.7". No. Go 1.10 is no longer supported.  "I can't use the newest" the second No: You can, just do it.

Comment: Version queries like `go get firebase.google.com/go@v3` are not understood by Go 1.10. If I were you I would just refuse to do the job. But if you must: manually get (e.g. `git clone`) the required deps, checkout the needed versions (`git checkout version`) and I would try to build like that.

Comment: @Volker Ofc I can use the newest Go version. I even have this program already working in Go `1.18` but with this version, even simple "Hello world" does not start on XP. The version `1.12` is the first when I can run sth simple but with `firebase` SDK it throws an error which I described in the question.

Comment: And you should not use XP.

Comment: @icza Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I failed after a few attempts and I decided to integrate with RTDB via Rest API. It seems that everything works fine in 1.12 even with listening to changes via SSG